# Error on Trigger Syntax using IF-THEN-ELSE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have four tables

- `Processor_products` with columns `Name` and `Socket`
- `Motherboard` with columns `Name` and `Socket`
- `Build` with columns `Processor` (references `Processor_products(Name)`] and `Motherboard` [references `Motherboard(Name)`]
- `Compatibility` with columns `compatible` and `id`

I want to write Trigger that inserts "No" in Compatibilty.compatible if the Processor and Motherboard inserted into Build have different Socket's or inserts "Yes" if they have the same Socket.

```
CREATE TRIGGER compatibility
AFTER INSERT ON build
BEGIN
IF ((SELECT * FROM build WHERE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) EXISTS (SELECT * FROM processor_products pp, motherboard m where pp.Socket <> m.Socket))
THEN
INSERT INTO compatibility(compatibility) VALUE('no');
ELSE
INSERT INTO compatibility(compatibility) VALUE('yes');
END IF;
END
```

I am using phpmyadmin and the error is that my syntax is wrong.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
>       IF ((SELECT * FROM build WHERE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) EXISTS (SELECT *' at line 3

Can someone help me?

The tables:

```
Build table = https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxviV.png
Motherboard = https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YNAo.png
Processors = https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOVjU.png
```

Comment: At first seight it feels/seams like a missing `DELIMITER`, but not checked for other syntax errors or unlogical errors..

Comment: pretty much sure that phpmyadmin (mysql to be correct) is telling you also what the error is... want to share with us the error message?

Comment: I still get a syntax error after adding it.
I have edited my question with error message.

Comment: *"
I still get a syntax error after adding it. I have edited my question with error message."* in short that trigger code is a mess `FOR EACH ROW` seams to be missing .. Also `SELECT * FROM build WHERE ORDER BY` is used with out a valid `WHERE` condition .. Like i said i didn't check for other syntax problems

Comment: .. also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as your trigger code depends on existing tables and data..

Comment: adding `for each row` and removing `where` now gives this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT * FROM processor_products pp, motherboard m where pp.Socket <> m.' at line 4`

Comment: That complete trigger code needs to have a complete rewrite so see that link how to provide example data and expected results.. ... Also the question is if it would be better if you would generate yes or no on runtime in SELECT or VIEW instead of storing it...

Comment: I have edited my post with images to my tables.
(I couldn't add them as links. Got an error saying I have unedited code in my post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without delving into the numerous problems with the syntax; and without delving into the actual problem the trigger is meant to address; setting all that discussion aside.

It looks like the trigger is attempting to: retrieve the value of the "`socket`" column from the related rows in `motherboard` and `processor` tables, and then compare those two string values, and then perform some other action based on the result of the comparison.

---

NOTE:

Do not use `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1` to identify the row that was just inserted.

Within the body of the AFTER INSERT trigger, we can reference values of the row that was just inserted by qualifying the column name with the `NEW` keyword.

For example, in the trigger, references to `NEW.motherboard` and `NEW.processor` will return the values of the `motherboard` and `processor` columns (respectively) of the row that was just inserted  (by the statement/row that caused the trigger to be fired.)

---

Here's a demonstration of a way we might approach writing an AFTER INSERT trigger that performs those operations:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_build_ai`
AFTER INSERT ON `build`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    -- local variables
    DECLARE ls_compatiblity VARCHAR(4)    DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE ls_p_socket     VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE ls_m_socket     VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT NULL;

    -- get "socket" values from motherboard and processor
    SELECT m.socket AS m_socket
         , p.socket AS p_socket
      FROM ( SELECT 1 AS n ) i
      LEFT
      JOIN ( -- retrieve related motherboard "socket" value
             SELECT ms.socket
               FROM motherboard ms
              WHERE ms.name   = NEW.motherboard
              ORDER BY ms.name, ms.socket
              LIMIT 1
           ) m
      LEFT
      JOIN ( -- retrieve related processor "socket" value
             SELECT ps.socket
               FROM processor_product ps
              WHERE ps.name   = NEW.processor
              ORDER BY ps.name, ps.socket
              LIMIT 1
           ) p
      INTO ls_m_socket
         , ls_p_socket
    ;

    -- check if values are equal
    IF ( ls_m_socket = ls_p_socket ) THEN
       SET ls_compatibility := 'yes'; 
    ELSE
       SET ls_compatibility := 'no';
    END IF;

    -- (not even going to try to fathom why we need to INSERT into another table)
    INSERT INTO `compatibility` ( `compatibility` ) VALUES ( ls_compatibility );

 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```